# i am pushing data to mongodb using php its done successfully but structure is wrong. why its generating 0 object?

Tags: php, mongodb

php code:

```
$data = array('$push' => array("scap" => array(
                            "loan" => array(array("user_profile_id"=>"","current_gross_loan"=>$userScapData['OutstandingLoans'],"_id"=>"","details"=>array())),
                            "tax" => array(array("user_profile_id"=>"","current_gross_income"=>$userScapData['Tax'],"_id"=>"","details"=>array())),
                            "essentials" => array(array("user_profile_id"=>"","current_gross_essentials"=>$userScapData['Essentials'],"_id"=>"","details"=>array())),
                            "lifesyle" => array(array("user_profile_id"=>"","current_gross_lifestyle_annual"=>$userScapData['LifestyleAnnual'],"current_gross_lifestyle_lumpsum"=>$userScapData['LifestyleLumpsum'],"_id"=>"","details"=>array())),
                            "responsibility" => array(array("user_profile_id"=>"","current_gross_responsibility_annual"=>$userScapData['ResponsibilityAnnual'],"current_gross_responsibility_lumpsum"=>$userScapData['ResponsibilityAnnual'],"_id"=>"","details"=>array())),
                            "legacy" => array(array("user_profile_id"=>"","current_gross_legacy"=>$userScapData['Legacy'],"_id"=>"","details"=>array())),
                            "cahrity" => array(array("user_profile_id"=>"","current_gross_charity_percentage"=>"","current_gross_charity_purchase"=>$userScapData['Charity'],"_id"=>"","details"=>array())),
                            "real_estate" => array(array("user_profile_id"=>"","current_gross_real_estate_monthly"=>$userScapData['RealEstateMonthly'],"current_purchase_amount"=>$userScapData['RealEstatePurchase'],"_id"=>"","details"=>array()))            
                    )
            ));
            $userScapCol = $db->user_scenarios;
            $_id = new MongoId($userScapData['ScenarioId']);
            $userScapCol->update(array("_id"=>$_id),array('$push' => $data));

**IMG-1**
**My output:-**
```

Its generating 0 object why i don't know i want output like IMG-2. what is wrong in my array

[image]

**IMG-2**
**I want below output**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) as of programming languages, appends to an array.

> If the field is absent in the document to update, $push adds the array field with the value as its element.

To add document of structure you have, you need just to [insert](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php), or uprade without `$push`:

```
$userScapCol->update(array("_id"=>$_id), $data['$push']);
```

Anyway check twice, because you are sending in your original request:

```
array('$push' => array('$push' => array(/* ... */)))
```

what may behave odd.